# Reusable component/mixin for a form that is disabled during submit in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have many components that are basically a form that, on submit, makes a request to the server and disables its input elements until a response is received. I'd like to not have to care about this disabling every time and factor it out into something reusable. Is there a good way to do that?

For concreteness, here is a minimal example:

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="send">
  <fieldset :disabled="isDisabled">
    <div>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input v-model="u.name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" v-model="u.email">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

As you can see, handling this `isDisabled` state clutters up the component:

```
data () {
  return {
    u: {
      name: '',
      email: '',
    },
    isDisabled: false
  }
},
methods: {
  send: function () {
    this.isDisabled = true
    api.post('/users/create', {
      name: this.u.name,
      email: this.u.email
    }).then(response => {
      this.isDisabled = false
      <do something>
    }).catch(error => {
      alert(error)
      this.isDisabled = false
    })
  }
}
```

One idea was to make a generic Form component parametrized by the required fields and REST endpoint, passed in by props. However, the forms and their `send` functions vary considerably, and might also include conditional inputs so this seems difficult to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite happy with the way I ended up doing it. My form component is basically just

```
<template>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="send">
    <fieldset :disabled="submitting">
      <slot></slot>
      <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" :value="submitText">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</template>
```

plus some code for displaying error messages. The component is parametrized by props, notably the endpoint to send data to, the payload, and the text in the button.

With slots, the actual form lives in the parent component and the computation of the payload is also done there, it is easy to have forms that contain very different inputs, unlike my first idea of passing the fields, their types and their name in the payload themselves as props. For concreteness, I usually make a computed property like this:

```
formdata: function () {
  return {
    endpoint: '/events/create',
    submitText: 'Create event',
    payload: {
      description: this.ev.description,
      date: this.date
    }
  }
}
```

and pass it with

```
<sync-form v-bind="formdata">
```

The `send` method in the form component takes care of disabling/un-disabling, and emits an `ok` or `err` event depending on the response. Optionally, the parent component can pass in a prop that tells the form if the input is valid and can be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), but all it would do is declare the `isDisabled` data item (which I would recommend you call `saving` so that it better indicates program state).

Since you set it to `false` in both the resolve and reject phases of the Promise, you can move it to the [`finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) phase, which would help the perceived clutter a bit.

You could possibly have a `directive` in your mixin that would find all the form elements in the form and disable them when saving, and re-enable them afterward, so the markup in the template would just be

```
<form v-disable-elements="saving">
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a FormContainer.vue which also passes the data as described here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots

```
<template>
  <form
    @submit.prevent="submit">
    <slot v-bind:formInfo="formInfo"></slot>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    onSubmit: Function
  },
  data () {
    return {
      formInfo: {
        submitting: false
      }
    }
  },
methods: {
  async submit () {
    try {
      this.formInfo.submitting = true
      const response = await this.onSubmit()
      this.$emit('onSuccess', response)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err', err)
      this.$emit('onError', err)
    }
    this.formInfo.submitting = false
  }
}
</script>
```

In a child I can do

```
<template>
<form-container
  :onSubmit="onSubmit"
  @onSuccess="onSuccess"
  @onError="onError"
  v-slot="{formInfo}">
    <input type="text" v-model="email" />
    <button>{{ formInfo.submitting ? 'Submitting...' : 'Submit' }}</button>
</form-container>
</template>

<script>
import FormContainer from './FormContainer'

export default {
  components: {
    FormContainer
  },
  data () {
    return {
      email: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit () {
      // Your axios or grahql call or whatever
    },
    onSuccess (res) {
      // Whatever you want to do after the submit succeeded
      console.log('Submitted!', res)
    },
    onError (err) {
      // Whatever you want to do after the submit failed
      console.log('Submit failed!', err)
    }
  }
</script>
```